# Authorship of Mishna

Tags: sources-mekorot, mishna, authorship

The Gemara in Yevamot 5oa clearly assumes that R. Yehuda Hanassi authored the Mishna:

> אמר רב יוסף כאן שנה רבי משנה שאינה צריכה

Are there any tannaic sources that also state that he authored the Mishna (e.g. a Tosefta, that is an actual tannaic source, not an Ammoraic source referencing tannaim)?

---

I am aware that there is debate regarding his role in the authorship. My question isn't whether he authored, compiled, or redacted. My question is only whether there is a tannaic source for any of the above.

EDIT: In order of priority to answering the question:

1. A Tannaic source.
2. Some proof that there is no Tannaic source (ignorance being a poor proof).
3. A distant third: a very thorough analysis on Rabbi Yehudah HaNassi's role in compiling the Mishnah.

Comment: Edited and compiled, not wrote.

Comment: @sabbahillel it's a machlokes

Comment: It's a machlokes Rashi and the Rambam

Comment: @sabbahillel ,according to the Rambam in his hakdama in the Mishna Torah he writes that Rebbi wrote (chibur)

Comment: @sam Doesn't _chiber_ mean "put together", like in _Vayakhel_ 36:13?

Comment: read the hakdama its mashmah simply he made the actual text

Comment: @sabbahillel I am aware of the famous dispute between Rambam and R. Sherira Gaon (although I think this is one version of the letter) regarding R. Judah the Prince's role. Both agree however that he played some role. The question was a tannaic source for this.

Comment: Why the comment-less downvote?

Comment: @Sam Rambam states there וכן היה הדבר תמיד עד רבינו הקדוש והוא קבץ כל השמועות וכל הדינין וכל הביאורין והפירושין ששמעו ממשה רבינו ושלמדו בית דין של כל דור ודור בכל התורה כולה וחבר מהכל ספר המשנה ושננו ברבים ונגלה לכל ישראל וכתבוהו כולם ורבצו בכל מקום כדי שלא תשתכח תורה שבעל פה מישראל.

Comment: And.............

Comment: @Sam והוא קבץ. I think there is a semantic issue going on here but collecting previous works, and even rewording them is still called compiling and redacting, not authoring. This is all in Rambams own opinion. See also the Tosafos and Rabi Akiva Eiger i mentioned in my answer. There were previous versions of 'Mishna', we even have some.

Answer (score 1):

The earliest personality I've seen referencing Rabi Yehuda HaNasi's compiling of the Mishna is a statement of Rabi Yochanan, his student.

See Bava Kamma 94b אמר רבי יוחנן בימי רבי נשנית משנה זו.

We find Rabi Yochanan being called Rebi's student in Psachim 3b.

There is also a give and take in Bava Metzia 44a between Rabi Yehuda and his son Rabi Shimon where the latter asks the former why he changed his teaching in the mishna from as earlier version.

As an aside, as pointed out by @Sabbahillel,  authored is probably the wrong word to describe what he did. See Tosafos in B.K. there, and see also the last mishna in Keilim with Rabi Akiva Eiger.

Comment: I dont see anything in that quote about rebbi compiling the Mishna, only that the task was performed in his time.

Comment: @mevaqesh did you see tosafos? Why would he bother mentioning Rebbi if the qualification of the law was not attributed to him?

Comment: I didnt see Tosafos, and I dont know R. Yochanan or why he mentioned Rebbi in particular to define the epoch. Perhaps he singled him out because he was his rebbi and / or the gaddol hador.

Comment: @Mevaqesh I would suggest learning the Tosafos

Comment: If the Tosafos is essential to appreciating your answer, consider editing it in.

Comment: @Mevaqesh it's only essential to preclude saying something like 'Perhaps he singled him out because he was his rebbi and / or the gaddol hador'. Something I didn't think anyone would suggest. And am still surprised that you did.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It does not provide a Tannaic source, nor does it somehow prove that there is not one. Please delete it.

Comment: @mevaqesh מתני ליה רבי לרבי שמעון בריה הזהב קונה את הכסף א''ל רבי שנית לנו בילדותיך הכסף קונה את הזהב ותחזור ותשנה לנו בזקנותיך הזהב קונה את הכסף בילדותיה מאי סבר ובזקנותיה מאי סבר  I'm assuming you saw these words and have a weird way of translating them? See also the top rashi on amud beis. According to that pshat, he actually changed from what he had learned from his teacher, Rabbi Meir.

Comment: Repeatedly jabs at my critical reading skills are unprofessional, against site policy, and quite frankly not very nice. That being said, the verb תנא is used to mean teaching a Mishnah, including by those trained to recite Mishnayot; not just those who authored them. We see that Rabbi taught in accordance with the Mishnah, but not that he authored, or compiled, it. See Megillah 18b and 26b for examples of usage of the exact same verb form מתני, which have absolutely nothing to do with authorship of Mishnayot.

Comment: @mevaqesh If you wouldn't try so hard to be vague and mysteriously convoluted people would be able to reply to your ideas based on logical premise. The Mishna was not wikipedia. If Rebbi got to change it, the assumption is he compiled, or at least had a hand in compiling it.

Comment: Rather than responding in ad hominem kind I will repeat, besides for not providing a tannaic source or evidence of dearth, which the question requested, rendering the answer a non-answer, the GM BM states nothing about changing a Mishnah. Rather it says that Rabbi taught a teaching (which also appears in a Mishna) but previously taught a different teaching. The Gemara says nothing about Mishnayot, let alone, about changing them. Given that I am sure you looked up the parallel passages I referenced, I would think there would be little to talk about.

Comment: @mevaqesh "which also" sounds a little desperate. I'm sure you are aware of the indications of the words מתני and שנית so I don't know why you are pushing this weird agenda.  Not weird for the inquiry, weird for ignoring the evidence.

Comment: @user6591 Desperate or not, please just edit in explicitly what the quote you are referencing is, and how you see it as implying an answer to the question. If someone doesn't find your read convincing, so be it.

Comment: @Double I have no problem if someone doesn't find my answer convincing or want to accept standard reading of common phrases. I'm not sure what edit you think would help. Usually at point in answer on this site I've been worn out from wanting to even attempt anything to try to be more helpful. It usually just ends up in a bigger headache for me.