# Is there internal evidence within the Mishnah that Rabbi Yehudah ha-Nasi redacted it?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mishna, tannaim

Without drawing upon later sources like the Gemara, Rabbi Sherira Gaon, Rashi, Maimonedes and others, is there internal evidence (or explicit claims) in the Mishnah itself that Rabbi Yehudah ha-Nasi redacted the Mishnah?

Comment: The chapter break after the first chapter in Avot is certainly suggestive (if it's original). Although the citation in 2:2 to רַבָּן גַּמְלִיאֵל בְּנוֹ שֶׁל רַבִּי יְהוּדָה הַנָּשִׂיא indicates some other stuff came in later.

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57825/759

Comment: I've heard this is why Rebbi always says אומר אני, since the rest of tannaic material is him quoting others.

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: Please see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60565/what-was-rabbi-yehuda-hanassis-role-in-compiling-the-mishnah what-was-rabbi-yehuda-hanassis-role-in-compiling-the-mishnah

Comment: @N.T. To me it personally matters, because otherwise it takes away from the credibility of the Mishnah

Comment: There is enough historical evidence that the Mishna was considered binding by the Talmud, and that it was written by Rebbi.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132985/discussion-between-randomuser-and-n-t).